# Install additional required components unknown error occurs Xcode 11.0

Tags: xcode

Install additional required components? 
Xcode requireds additional components to support running and debugging. Choose install to add required components. 
I found someone said(from: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/124031): 
I would try na different sequence:

- Restart computer, and if that's not enough:
- Delete Xcode
- Restart computer
- Install Xcode from App Store

I don't want to delete xcode, do you have any good idea? Thank you.

[image]

MacOS update to 10.15.1 
[image]

Installing Components...
An unknown error occured. See the Install log from more detail.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, When I update the Xcode to latest version Xode 11.2.1. 
Installing components...
[image]

Xcode Version 11.2.1
[image]